# In C#, how to add Intellisense to DataGridView cells?

Tags: c#, datagridview, intellisense

I would expect this would be a common need.  Can anyone help or point me to a page that explains how to do this?

Comment: Can you provide more details?  Maybe a code snippet or two ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean like the auto-complete options on `TextBox`, I'm not aware of any in-built support for this. The closest (although not the same) would be to use a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`.

For things *not* directly available; it looks like other people have looked at this - you might try the sample [here](http://www.vb-tips.com/DataGridViewAutoComplete.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that getting data of dataGridView from database with textbox button textChanged event do this.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string query = "select Emp_ID,Emp_Name,Father_Name,Email from Employee where Emp_Name like '" + textBox1.Text + "%' ORDER BY Emp_Name ASC";
using (SqlCommand comand = new SqlCommand(query, con))
{
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
da.SelectCommand = comand;
DataTable ds = new DataTable();
ds.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
da.Fill(ds);
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
}
}
```